# Is there any way to shrink a picture size & keep the same pixels of the original?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, creative-cloud

there is this option on YouTube channels to make yourself a cover photo (banner) but since YouTube has modified the channels layout to fit both TV's PC's & mobiles this thing became quite tricky. the maximum size should be 2560 - 1440 & the minimum should be 2048 - 1152. in the maximum option there is an option to do some adjustment, even though you don't have enough freedom to crop it however you like & it's not applied on all the territory of the pic. in the minimum size you cant edit the picture after the upload. for me, obviously, the minimum size is better since you can see more of the original photo. but, there are still MAJOR parts that are missing from the original and I want people to expose to the same photo that it "only" took me hours to find. my question is (at last) is there any way to shrink a photo size without changing the pixels?

I'm new so i couldn't add 2 links for example :(

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

So, if by shrink you mean that you want to fit a 12px by 12px image into, say, a 2px by 2px space and have the image remain the same pixel size, the answer is no you can't do that.

**However**, for your youtube banner image, if you really want your visitors to be able to see the whole thing, I suggest popping it into photoshop and setting the canvas size to the required size for a youtube banner (2048 x 1152) and then fitting you whole image within that space. Now, when you do this, you're going to have to have some white space (or whatever color) surrounding your image to make it fit properly.

Take this for example:

[image: example youtube banner image fitting the whole picture into the space]

Here, I get to display the whole image I want, but I have to have some "white space" on the sides. You can choose a color that goes with your image to place on the sides as well. That will probably help it look nicer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did what you suggested & it didn't really showed the whole picture. here's an example of how it looks in a channel. there are really beautiful parts in the pic you cant see. https://postimg.org/image/ocrbqhds3/

Comment: & this is the original picture https://postimg.org/image/4zfhf5799/

Comment: Okay so that problem is due to the automatic cropping that Youtube does on your banner photo depending on where you're looking at it. For example, if you were to look at the image I resized on the TV youtube app, you would see the whole thing, but on a laptop, you're only going to see a slice of it. The dimensions of that slice are probably something like 300x1152 and I don't think you want to size your image to fit in that space. It'll look really odd.

Comment: how it will look through a pc is what important for me the most. what i asked was is there any way to make the channel picture look as same as it can to the original one (when you watch the pic on YouTube through a pc) & still somehow keep the pixels in 2048 x 1152

Comment: @RonenGoaStar the short answer is no. The minimum width the banner image will be displayed when viewed on a desktop is 1546 x 423. This is called the “safe area” and is always visible to users. So you want to fit the most important part of your image in this space. If you need more help, youtube provides a [banner image template](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2972003?hl=en) that has photoshop and fireworks files.